# Remove Create an account link in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to remove create an account link. can you help me how can I do?

[image]

Comment: Hello @kiran, did Brockfast's solution worked ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

If you extended Luma Theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/m/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body> 
            <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->
    </body>
</page>
```

if you want to remove OR

Add this less

```
.header.panel  {
    > .header.links {
        > .authorization-link {
            &:after {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

Add this css

```
.header.panel > .header.links > .authorization-link:after {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I tried and create an account removed but i want to remove OR also

Comment: answer  is update can you check please

Answer (score 2):

To remove "Create an Account" link add below code in the default.xml

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: thanks but i want to remove OR also ex. Sign in Or create an account?

Comment: Or will disappear automatically if you add this. Did in my case, at least.

Comment: i check inspect element and code <li class="authorization-link" data-label="or">
    <a href="http://evolutioncorp.club/customer/account/login/">
        Sign In    </a>
</li> if i remove data-label =or then it's correct so which file i need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing `<referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>` into your theme's default.xml will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

**To Remove "Create an Account" link create default.xml under to your theme like "app/design/frontend/Theme/Demo/Magento_Customer/layout".**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock  name="register-link" remove="true"/>
        </body>
    </page>
```